# sasl_username does not appear in my maillog logfile

Tags: postfix, sasl

I've got some servers that do not log the user when processing mail.

Packages involved are `postfix 2:2.11.5-centos5.15072015` and `cyrus-sasl-2.1.22-7.el5_8.1.x86_64`

There is no sasl_username on the logfile line:

I expect to see somethin like this:

```
Mar 14 10:53:12 aaaaaaaaa postfix/smtpd[20132]: 327251422492: 
client=c-66-xxx-xxx-xxx.hsd1.fl.comcast.net[66.xxx.xxx.xxx], 
sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=xxxxx@yyyyy.com
```

Instead I see:

```
Mar 14 10:53:12 bbbbbbbbbb postfix/smtpd[20132]: 327251422492: 
client=ptr.domain.tld[66.xxx.xxx.xxx]
```

In other words, the `sasl_method` and `sasl_username` is missing.

Everywhere I google `sasl_username`, the postings I read all assume that `sasl_username` is there, and nobody tells how to turn it on.

Thanks

Comment: What about http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header ?

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 5 is using most of the packages from ~2005 and got last regular update in ~2014. You are strongly advised to update to something recent and supported (CentOS 6 will get some updates yet, but latest version is CentOS 7).

The difference is most probably caused by the using the old version of your packages. Give it a try, upgrade or install some more recent system and you should be fine.